# Sending data to server

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card, web-server, sram

I have an SD card have a very big file (1M character). i try to load it into memory in terms of 4K character array ( The maximum I could do using Arduino Mega). but this take almost 250 call to the server. And this is too much. Is there any way better to do it. I am using firebase as my server and i am touching the limit and this is inacceptable to the stability of the program

Comment: So I guess you are using an ESP8266 with AT firmware for Wifi connection? Or do you use an ethernet shield?

Comment: `client.write(file);` doesn't work?

Comment: @chrisl I use SIM800L

Comment: @Juraj I guess this is not available i use micro sd interface and SIM800L and there is no such function as you mentioned

Comment: I don't think, that you can get around the 4k limitation with this hardware. Is the number of calls the problem, or the time needed for doing the whole transmission?

Comment: @chrisl Both are problems

Comment: please post your code ... overwrite any sensitive information

Comment: I doubt that the GSM can send data in such large chunks. on TCP networks data are send in 1.5kB packets. so I doubt making the buffer larger will help. it is simply how things are done: read buffer, write buffer until everything is copied. I guess the optimal buffer size will be 512 bytes or less

Comment: @Juraj Ok, Is there any better solution to send data to servers in this large chunks?

Comment: better? put the SD card in a computer

Comment: I need to send data periodically and automatically